# The given credentials or configuration format does not fits to the storage provider (Sharpbox)

Tags: vb.net, token, dropbox, sharpbox

I am new to cloud storage, I encountered this error

> The given credentials or configuration format does not fits to the storage provider

when I tried to read a txt file with token (uploadMe sub). I am using vb. Looking forward to your reply.

My code:

```
Dim ConsumerKey As String = "******************"
Dim ConsumerSecret As String = "*****************"
Dim config As DropBoxConfiguration = DropBoxConfiguration.GetStandardConfiguration()
Dim requestToken As DropBoxRequestToken

  Private Sub AuthorizeMe()
    config.AuthorizationCallBack = New Uri("http://www.google.com")
    requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret)
    Dim AuthorizationUrl As String = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxAuthorizationUrl(config, requestToken)
    Process.Start(AuthorizationUrl)
End Sub

   Private Sub saveMyAuth()
    Dim accessToken As ICloudStorageAccessToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.ExchangeDropBoxRequestTokenIntoAccessToken(config, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, requestToken)
    Dim DropboxStorage As New CloudStorage()
    DropboxStorage.Open(config, accessToken)

    Dim File As FileStream = New FileStream("c:\TEMP\MyToken.txt", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
    DropboxStorage.SerializeSecurityTokenToStream(requestToken, File)
    File.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub uploadme()
    Try
        Dim configio As DropBoxConfiguration = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox)
        Dim DropboxStorage As New CloudStorage()
        Dim accessToken As ICloudStorageAccessToken
         Using fs = File.Open("C:\TEMP\MyToken.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)

            accessToken = DropboxStorage.DeserializeSecurityToken(fs)
        End Using
        DropboxStorage.Open(configio, accessToken)
        Dim srcFile = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\TEMP\mysqlbackup.xml")
        DropboxStorage.UploadFile(srcFile, "/")
        DropboxStorage.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Beep()
        Console.Write(ex.Message, "")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please at least tell us which line of code is triggering the exception. Ideally, give us the full stack trace.

Comment: One quick idea: it looks like you're saving the request token instead of the access token.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!!!It was too obvious to check that variable